# Include nested entity details but don't group by then when grouping by other fields

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq, highcharts

I working with Database first C# MVC, EF6, LINQ and JSon to try and pass data to both Highcharts and Google Maps for some of my reporting.

If I could add an image I would show you the relevant portion of my model, but sadly I need more reputation to do that...

The portion of the Entity Model I'm concentrating on right now is based on a central Docket that contains a BuildingCode as part of a one-to-many relationship to a building with and address and further relationship to the buildings polygons (for mapping). Dockets are also classified by one or more DocketTypes and thus there is a many-to-many relationship between Dockets and DocketTypes, which is not directly exposed to through the EF.

As an example a Docket which represents an investigation, could be related to the theft of a mobile phone in building A located on Campus X, not only was the cellphone stolen but the assailant also assaulted the victim in order to steal the mobile phone. So there are 2 DocketTypes here 1. Theft of mobile phone and 2. assault. Note: this is fictitious and for illustration purposes only .

One of my fundamental reports requires that I count how many docketTypes affect each building and each campus in a given period. When I display this I also need to show what the DocketTypes are.

I have no end of nightmare trying to find a way to get this right, I keep running into circular reference errors and needing to use explicit conversions when trying to model the data with LINQ so that I can pass a single nested object through JSON to the client side where displaying will occur.

In the below code I am told I need an Explicit conversion:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Campus_Investigator.ViewModels.DocketTypeViewModel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Campus_Investigator.ViewModels.DocketTypeViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

```
var currentDocketQuery = from d in db.Dockets
                 from dt in d.DocketTypes
                 from bp in d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons
                 where d.OccurrenceStartDate >= datetime && d.BuildingDetail.CampusName == Campus

                 select new CampusBuildingDocketTypeViewModel()
                 {
                     BuildingCode = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingCode,
                     BuildingName = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingName,
                     //BuildingPolygons = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons,
                     DocketTypes = new DocketTypeViewModel()
                     {
                         Category = dt.Category,
                         SubCategory = dt.SubCategory,
                         ShortDescription = dt.ShortDescription
                     }
                 };
```

I appreciate any ideas on how I can explicitly convert this or is that a better method I can use and avoid the `circular reference error`?

Comment: the error message is clear: you want to set DocketTypes in your return value to a DocketTypeViewModel, however it is a SET of DocketTypeViewModels.

Comment: In my `CampusBuildingDocketTypeViewModel` class DocketTypes is defined as follows: `public IEnumerable<DocketTypeViewModel> DocketTypes { get; set; }` So isn't DocketTypes then a SET?

Answer (score 1):

You included some redundant part in your query (which performs some inner join). The `from bp in d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons` is joined in but then is not shown in the result. So it totally does not make sense. There may be duplicated elements in the result due to that. The `from dt in d.DocketTypes` is wrong joined in, although you need it in the result but because the `DocketTypes` is output ***per d in db.Dockets***, so it's just simply queried like this:

```
var currentDocketQuery = from d in db.Dockets
                         where d.OccurrenceStartDate >= datetime && d.BuildingDetail.CampusName == Campus
                         select new CampusBuildingDocketTypeViewModel()
                         {
                          BuildingCode = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingCode,
                          BuildingName = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingName,
                          //BuildingPolygons = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons,
                          DocketTypes = d.DocketTypes
                         };
```

In fact I can see the commented line `//BuildingPolygons = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons`, so if you want to include that, it should also work.

If the `DocketTypes` has different type of `d.DocketTypes`, then you need a simple projection like this:

```
var currentDocketQuery = from d in db.Dockets
                         where d.OccurrenceStartDate >= datetime && d.BuildingDetail.CampusName == Campus
                         select new CampusBuildingDocketTypeViewModel()
                         {
                          BuildingCode = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingCode,
                          BuildingName = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingName,
                          //BuildingPolygons = d.BuildingDetail.BuildingPolygons,
                          DocketTypes = d.DocketTypes.Select(e => new DocketTypeViewModel()
                                                             {
                                                               Category = e.Category,
                                                               SubCategory = e.SubCategory,
                                                               ShortDescription = e.ShortDescription
                                                             })
                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one by using the below. The major hassle with this is the circular referencing that exists in the model. When JSON serializes these, everything falls apart so it takes a lot of transforming to make sure that I only extract what I need. In this case grouped campus and building data (below includes the polygons which where only half commented out in the above) and then the include the detail of the DocketTypes that occurred at each building.

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);

var campusDocket = from d in db.Dockets
               where d.OccurrenceStartDate >= datetime && d.BuildingDetail.CampusName == Campus
               group d by new { d.BuildingDetail.CampusName, d.BuildingDetail.BuildingCode, d.BuildingDetail.BuildingName } into groupdata
               select new CampusBuildingDocketTypeViewModel
               {
                   BuildingCode = groupdata.Key.BuildingCode,
                   BuildingName = groupdata.Key.BuildingName,
                   CampusName = groupdata.Key.CampusName,
                   Count = groupdata.Count(),
                   BuildingPolygons = from bp in db.BuildingPolygons
                                      where bp.BuildingCode == groupdata.Key.BuildingCode
                                      select new BuildingPolygonViewModel
                                      {
                                          Accuracy = bp.Accuracy,
                                          BuildingCode = bp.BuildingCode,
                                          PolygonOrder = bp.PolygonOrder,
                                          Latitude = bp.Latitude,
                                          Longitude = bp.Longitude
                                      },
                   DocketTypes = from doc in db.Dockets
                                 from dt in doc.DocketTypes
                                 where doc.OccurrenceStartDate >= datetime && doc.BuildingCode == groupdata.Key.BuildingCode
                                 select new DocketTypeViewModel
                                 {
                                     Category = dt.Category,
                                     SubCategory = dt.SubCategory,
                                     ShortDescription = dt.ShortDescription
                                 }
               };
```

The Answer again is ViewModels. I'm finding ViewModels seem to solve a lot of problems...